# How to save custom object into sqlite on windows phone using c#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

How to save custom object into sqlite on windows phone using c#?

```
 public class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public List<Address> Items { get; set; }

}
public class Address
{
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string pin { get; set; }
}
```

how to insert  Person into sqlite database and how to read ?

Comment: Which wrapper are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample of my code:

```
    private const string db_name = "store4.sqlite";
    SQLiteAsyncConnection connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(db_name);


    public async void InsertInspections(ObservableCollection<Inspections> inspections)
    {
        connection.CreateTableAsync<Inspections>().Wait();

        foreach (var inspection in inspections)
        {
            var task = connection.Table<Inspections>().
                Where(v => v.InspectionId == inspection.InspectionId).ToListAsync();
            task.Wait();

            if (task.Result.Any())
                connection.UpdateAsync(inspection);
            else
                connection.InsertAsync(inspection);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this code applies for the same sqlite wrapper rams is using. Also your code does not handle relationships (which I guess was the most important part of the question). And: Never use async void unless it's an event handler.

Comment: Can you please explain about 'async void'?

Comment: `async void` basically means fire and forget. If there are any exceptions inside that method you probably won't be able to trace them. This is highly dangerous and should only be used for atomic operations that are either safe or not important. Considered there is no safety and that you should be able to debug your code at anytime you should return a Task. Also you should not use wait(). Use await.

Comment: here what is "Inspections"? the class should be like my class ...can you please try my custom class and let me know it is working...
i am not getting solution for that if any one knows can you please help me .....

Comment: Inspection is a class like your Person class.  Inspections is a collection of Inspections).